# How can i call a dyn function stored within a Box?

Tags: generics, rust, function-pointers, traits

I have this snippet:

```rs
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub struct TaskGroup
{
    task_group: Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Fn() -> dyn Iterator<Item=usize>>>>,
}

impl TaskGroup
{
    fn foo(&self)
    {
        for task in self
                .task_group
                .lock()
                .unwrap()()
        {}
    }
}
```

Which returns:

```
error[E0618]: expected function, found `MutexGuard<'_, Box<(dyn Fn() -> (dyn Iterator<Item = task::TaskHandle> + 'static) + 'static)>>`
  --> crates/thread_pool/src/task.rs:60:25
   |
60 |               for task in self // task
   |  _________________________^
61 | |                 .post_reqs // RwLock
62 | |                 .read() // handle
63 | |                 .unwrap() // Ref to TaskGroup
64 | |                 .task_group // TaskGroup
65 | |                 .lock()// Mutex lock
66 | |                 .unwrap()()
   | |_________________________^ this trait object returns an unsized value `(dyn Iterator<Item = task::TaskHandle> + 'static)`, so it cannot be called
```

So what is the correct way to call the function in the box and get the iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the same as why the following doesn't work:

```rust
fn f() -> dyn Iterator<Item = usize> {
    0..10
}
```

You're attempting to return something that doesn't have a size known at compile-time. If it was a regular `fn`, then you could replace `dyn` with [`impl` (or return position impl trait)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/impl_trait.html#as-a-return-type) and everything would work fine. However, since you're dealing with closures, then things get a bit more complicated. You need to box it.

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

let f: Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Fn() -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>>>> =
    Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(|| Box::new((0..10).into_iter()))));

let mut guard = f.lock().unwrap();
let f = guard.as_mut();

for x in f() {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Remember to store the guard returned by `.lock()`. Otherwise the compiler will complain about a temporary being freed while still in use.